# How can I replicate this beautiful dialogue box?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

The field is:

```
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
```

When I enter an invalid value like 1.111 for example, it gives this nice dialogue box. I tried to replicate it for additional criteria first by adding custom validation, (because I thought it was is_valid() that was doing it) but turns out that error needs HttpRedirect and manual rendering. Then I realized it's probably a database constraint so I added a CheckConstraint, but that needs to be handled manually as well. Is it possible?

[image]

Edit: great, thanks to William, I added this to my html:

```
<input type='hidden' name='starting_bid' value='{{  listing.starting_bid  }}'>
```

Which renders as:

```
<input type='hidden' name='starting_bid' value='50.00'>
```

Now, how do I pass this in to the attr? Currently I have:

```
attrs={
    'min': F('starting_bid')
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: No this is not the `is_valid`, etc. It is a format specified in the HTML `<input>` item.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you! Could you please check the updated post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I defined the init method of the form:

```
class BidForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.starting_bid = kwargs.pop('starting_bid')
        self.current_bid = kwargs.pop('current_bid')
        super(BidForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['amount'].widget = forms.NumberInput(
                        attrs={
                'min': max(self.current_bid + Decimal(0.01) , self.starting_bid)
            }
        )
```

Then, in views.py:

```
if listing_selected.current_bid:
    form = BidForm(starting_bid=listing_selected.starting_bid, current_bid=listing_selected.current_bid.amount)
else:
    form = BidForm(starting_bid=listing_selected.starting_bid, current_bid=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would add the needed logic in the `def clean_bid_field(self):` validator in your forms.py.

```
<input type="number"... />
```

does some error-checking, too, depending on the params you give it.  See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number